Pymssql not filtering correctly
I have written a python REST API that extracts data from SQL server, compares it against a list of employees and then sends the data to another REST endpoint. When querying the database I have filtered out all non-numeric values, when I print the output only non-numeric values are displayed. However, when I pass the output to the endpoint method I am receiving the error "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'test employee' to data type int". This 'test employee' value does exist in the table but should have been filter out as I validated.
#Querying database
inactive_employee_query = f"SELECT EmployeeCode FROM Employee WHERE EmploymentEndDate IS NULL AND PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', EmployeeCode) = 0" 
inactive_employee_result = query_database(inactive_employee_query)

This is the method the result is passed to:
def delete_employees_from_syteline(inactive_in_syteline):
    token = get_access_token() 
    if token: 
        access_token = token.get('access_token') 
        token_type = token.get('token_type') 
        changes = [] 
        # Format the output JSON in the correct format for Syteline
        for entry in inactive_in_syteline: 
            employee_code = entry[0]
            change = {
                "Action": 2,
                "Properties": [
                    {
                        "Name": "EmpNum",
                        "Value": "   "+entry[0], # inserts employee_code value here
                        "Modified": False,
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "EmpStatus",
                        "Value": "TER", # sets employee status to terminated
                        "Modified": True,
                    }
 
                ],
                "UpdateLocking": 1
            }
            changes.append(change) # Adds the change item to the array

        # Format the payload to be sent to syteline endpoint
        payload = {
        "IDOName": "SLEmployees",
        "RefreshAfterSave": "true",
        "Changes": changes  # Attach the array as the payload
        }

        # Set the request headers
        headers = {
            'accept': 'application/json',  
            'Authorization': token_type+" "+access_token,
            'X-Infor-MongooseConfig': 'DPL_TEST',
            'X-TenantId': 'infor',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

        # Call the syteline endpoint passing payload and headers
        try: # try to send data to syteline endpoint
            response = requests.post(update_syteline_endpoint, json=payload, headers=headers, verify = False, timeout=300) # pass the endpoint, payload and headers to the request
            response.raise_for_status()
            return {  # Print the response in the console (for display/debug purpose only)
            "access_token": token_type+" "+access_token,  
            "response": response.json(), 
            "payload": payload 
            }
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e: # if data cannot be sent to the endpoint raise an error
            print(f"Error sending data to Syteline API: {e}")
            return {"error": str(e)} 

I cannot understand why the filter appears to have worked correctly when printing the output but when response is passed to API endpoint, data appears to be different.
